# Window is not defined, Vue smooth scroll - Nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to add vue smooth scroll to my nuxt.js project and am getting "window is not defined error".

my steps were:

```
yarn add vue2-smooth-scroll
```

in vue file:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import vueSmoothScroll from 'vue2-smooth-scroll';

Vue.use(vueSmoothScroll);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know for `vue2-smooth-scroll` specifically but when a vue dependency doesn't support SSR you can disable it in `nuxt.config.js`

So if you have `~/plugins/smooth-scroll.js` :

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import vueSmoothScroll from 'vue2-smooth-scroll';

Vue.use(vueSmoothScroll);
```

You can put this in `nuxt.config.js` :

```
// ...
plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/smooth-scroll', ssr: false }
  ],
// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only need it on client side, which would make sense for a library like this, there is an alternative way of registering the plugin in `nuxt.config.js`:

```
plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/smooth-scroll', mode: 'client' }
],
```

Comment: cool! much appreciated. do you know if there is caveats with using mode: 'client' vs using ssr: false??? This project is not an SPA so i'm wondering what disadvantages there could be with only rendering client side, if any.

Comment: just double checked the documentation, `ssr: false` is the same as `mode: client`. `ssr` seems to be deprecated since 2.5 if I understand it correctly. I don't think that is has disadvantages, it just depends if your plugin can run on both client and server or not.